# Split input text box into 2 but accept input as one

Tags: css, html

I want to split my input text box into two but accept input as if coming from a single input text box. For example, I need to accept the name of a person, but I wish to split the input text boxes as two separate text boxes labelled 'First Name' and 'Last Name'. Kindly use only CSS. Thank you!

Comment: I think you can only do such a thing with client side javascript, otherwise is there any reason you can't have 2 different fields and evaluate the values server side?

Comment: can't be done without js

Comment: You could just style your form's css so it looks like they're next to each other. But you really need to have separate input fields if you want to store it separately.

Answer (score 4):

I did something with jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group" id="unified-inputs">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" />
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" style="display: none;" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="$().unifyInputs('first-name', 'last-name', 'name');" />
```

CSS:

```
body { margin: 10px; }
#unified-inputs.input-group { width: 100%; }
#unified-inputs.input-group input { width: 50% !important; }
#unified-inputs.input-group input:last-of-type { border-left: 0; }
```

jQuery:

```
$.fn.unifyInputs = function(firstName, secondName, finalName) {
    $("input[name='"+firstName+"']").hide();
    $("input[name='"+secondName+"']").hide();

    $("input[name='"+finalName+"']").show();
    $("input[name='"+finalName+"']").val($("input[name='"+firstName+"']").val()+" "+$("input[name='"+secondName+"']").val());
}
```

Take a look how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/f5gogmac/5/

Answer (score 0):

with only css you cannot handle values, but if you wish to save the value into the same place it is better to accept one field.

Anyway for better information handling it is better to handle two fields and save them separatly.

Hope this helps.